# Can RDD accessed from diffrent spark context

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I am new to spark. Is it possible to use RDD defined in different spark context ? if yes how .

Ie.

We create one RDD of a hive table t1 in spark context1 .

Can we will be able to use (refer) RDD in different spark job .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark wont support RDD sharing between two different sparkcontext but same can be achieved using

a] Tachyon

b] Apache Ignite : Ignite provices igniteContext using which you can share rdds. IgniteRDD is an implementation of native Spark RDD and DataFrame APIs which, in addition to all the standard RDD functionality, also shares the state of the RDD across other Spark jobs, applications and workers.

Reference : https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html

Comment: Can I access same IgniteRDD from different sessions created in different applications written in different languages (specifically java, scala and python)? (Asked [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607472/is-it-possible-to-accesss-apache-ignite-rdd-from-different-spark-session-from-di))

Answer (score 4):

An RDD is bound to an application, so it can't be shared across apps. You simply persist the data (e.g. on HDFS,S3) and read it from the other app as an RDD.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that with the help of apache ignite so go through following link
https://ignite.apache.org/